# Guild delete event returns undefined

Tags: discord.js

So my discord bot smartwiki was recently verified and I have this event where it just sends undefined idk why.. advaith told it comes cause one of the bot server is on an outage but I tried removing bot from some guilds and those guilds weren't on an outage but I get undefined (I have presence intent btw) also thsi isn't cause of intents cuz my guild create works fine this did too but it got undefined after my bot went verified

Code:

```
client.on('guildDelete', guild =>{ 
      client.user.setActivity(`Serving ${client.guilds.cache.size} Servers with a total of ${client.users.cache.size} users and ${client.channels.cache.size} Channels!`);
    const Logs = '809839910675546122'
    client.channels.cache.get(Logs).send(
    new Discord.MessageEmbed() 
    .setTitle("I Was Removed From a Guild :c")
    .addField("Guild Name" , `${guild.name}`)
    .addField("Guild Members" , `${guild.members.cache.size}`)
    .addField("Guild Id" , `${guild.id}`)
    .addField("Guild Owner" , `<@${guild.ownerID}> | Id: ${guild.ownerID}`)
    .setFooter(`SmartWiki is Currently in ${client.guilds.cache.size}guilds!`)
    .setTimestamp()
    .setThumbnail("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/776925179947384884/808370331856535582/standard_1.gif")
    .setColor('RED')
)

})
```

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDAbf.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Getting the same thing recently with my bot. Don't know why. Seems to appear before the bot logs in and also after, has been for a few days now. Only on bootup though. Odd...

Comment: I dont have enough reputation to comment sorry